# main: return 0 hangs, exit 0 closes. How to debug?

Tags: c++, multithreading, debugging, return, exit

I have a program that spawns three threads, does some communication between them, then closes them. The main thread waits for the last thread to close and then calls `return 0`.

But for some strange reason my program does not close but hangs when exiting with `return 0`, it closes fine with `exit(0)` however. I have already checked that the threads are really closed, I even forced them to close by issuing `pthread_kill(pid, 0)`. I also tried valgrind to look for leaking memory.

As far as I understand the only thing `exit()` is not doing is calling the destructors of locally scoped non-static objects, but neither is there one in my main function nor would that explain why it hangs.

What is causing that behavior? How could I debug this?

code:

- main.cpp: http://pastebin.com/7aN9KA6T
- publisher.hpp: http://pastebin.com/Vhz1FKau
- publisher.cpp: http://pastebin.com/09nh5YBs
- boxoffice.hpp: http://pastebin.com/kaEbgNMJ
- boxoffice.cpp: http://pastebin.com/wafaVcGV

Comment: I would guess it's something to do with the zmq objects you're using in your main function. If you google there are lots of discussions about zmq hanging on shutdown, so maybe have a look there.

Comment: Did you join or detach your threads before calling `return 0`?

Comment: The difference between `return` and `exit()` is that return invokes destructors of local objects. I'm not sure about destructors of global or static objects, but that could be another difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join each of your threads before returning.

```
bo_thread.join();
pub_thread.join();
sub_thread.join();
```

Also, `pthread_kill(pid, 0)` in the way you're using it has two issues.

1. It takes a `pthread_t` type, not a pid. This can be accessed through [boost::thread::native_handle](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.nativehandle)
2. Calling it doesn't actually 'kill' the thread. What it does depends on the second argument. With 0, it will just check if they're running. See the man page here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_kill.3.html

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this did not solve my situation. Thanks for pointing out that I misunderstood `pthread_kill`, but now that I have rtfm I printed the result and I received a `3`, that is ESRCH, so from what I understand, the threads do not exist anymore. Which they indeed shouldn't! So I guess the problem does indeed lie elsewhere.

Comment: To get more information you could get a stacktrace when the program is hanging with gdb. Run the program with `gdb a.out`, in the gdb prompt type `run`. When it hangs, hit `Ctrl+c` then type `thread apply all backtrace` to get a backtrace for all running threads. It might not give you source code locations as the libraries probably aren't built with debugging symbols, but it should give you the function names and which libraries they're in which can be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks Xiao, with your help I could track down the problem. I wasn't closing the zmq objects properly, as @jonathan-porter suggested.